# async file upload click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i want to fire file open dialogue of ajax async file upload using javascript
is it possible something like below

Example:
   var a= fileupload.click();

above syntax works for asp.net file upload control but not for async file upload.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx